# ReactiveX operators - debounce, but fires first, and filters others

Tags: rxjs, debouncing

I am looking for an operator that works similarly to `debounce(ms)`, but it fires the first event, then waits `ms` and then fires the first event and so on.

Basically, I would like to filter events that happen very close to each other (in terms of time), but not wait for the last one, but pick the first one instead.

Is there such an operator, or maybe it is not hard to make one?

Comment: Looks like [throttleTime](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttleTime) will do what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've actually compiled a comparative marble diagram for these operators, might be helpful as a cheatsheet:

[image: compare RxJS debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime operators]

As @oles-savluk already mentioned, you seem to need `throttleTime`

Play with it here: **[debounceTime vs throttleTime vs auditTime vs sampleTime](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/debounceTime-vs-throttleTime-vs-auditTime-vs-sampleTime/)**.

Hope this helps

Comment: You da real MVP

Comment: A bit about debounce and throttling inRxJS in  my article: https://blog.angularindepth.com/throttling-notifications-from-multiple-users-with-rxjs-4d90473f34aa